# Timestamp in nanopb

Tags: timestamp, protocol-buffers, nanopb

Is there support for google.protobuf.Timestamp datatype and encode decode function in nanopb ?  Or we should encode/decode as int64 or may be uint32 (if possible till year 2106) ? The target device is a 32bit MCU and  server end is a java based implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`google.protobuf.Timestamp` is just a "well known" message type. Its definition is available from [timestamp.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) in Google's repository:

```
message Timestamp {
  int64 seconds = 1;
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

You can build `timestamp.proto` using nanopb generator the same way you build other `.proto` files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a comment on a old post, but I had a similar question on the ESP32 and came across this so I thought I would chime in.

As stated by JPA, if you build the nanopb files it is fairly easy to use.

How I used it:

```
google_protobuf_Timestamp timestamp;
timestamp.seconds = esp_log_timestamp()/1000;
```

I was only interested in second intervals and not miliseconds so that is why I divided by 1000.

I works well and it is still encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timestamp.proto file from google protobuf package and compile it  with nanopb directly to generate timestamp.pb.h and timestamp.pb.c file.